# Can i use FileDataStore in AEM 6.1 with Apache Jackrabbit Oak 1.2.18 in TARMK

Tags: aem, jackrabbit, datastore

can i use FileDataStore in AEM 6.1 with Apache Jackrabbit Oak 1.2.18 in TARMK installation to store Blob file ?

I see in the Doc https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-1/deploy/platform/data-store-config.html#Data that FileDataStore is supported in Jackrabbit 2 .

so does this is compatible with Apache Jackrabbit Oak 1.2.18 ?

kindly help here.

```
> host:/crx-quickstart/install> cat org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.plugins.blob.datastore.FileDataStore.config
 #path to the DataStore
  path=./sling/repository/datastore
 #The minimum size of an object that should be stored in this data store.
   minRecordLength=4096
 #cache for storing small binaries in-memory
   cacheSizeInMB=128
host:/crx-quickstart/install> cat org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.plugins.segment.SegmentNodeStoreService.config
  customBlobStore=true
```

Answer (score 1):

Short answer is **Yes**

However, it is recommended to get the latest SP and CFP available from the AEM 6.1 [support page](https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/kb/aem61-available-hotfixes.html). OAK 1.2.26 is the latest version of OAK compatible with AEM 6.1 as of June '17.

Also, as per the setup documentation, the FileDataStore is supported and highly recommended for storing binaries outside of your TarMK for better performance and scalability.

The `org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.plugins.blob.datastore.FileDataStore.config` config file needs to be in the `install` folder of your AEM instance which is read at the startup of a fresh install to setup the data store.

> You cannot use this file to modify an existing instance storage.
>
> The `.config` extension may not always be recognised by AEM instance so try changing it to `.cfg` (old style config file). The syntax of your file in original question does not match the `.config` extension so just a thing to try.

Another important point to note is that if you want to use FileDataStore then you should delete the `rg.apache.jackrabbit.oak.plugins.blob.datastore.S3DataStore.config` file from your directory if present.

Comment: Doesn't we have to Enable the blob store ? In Segment.cfg to notify AEM regd. The blob files to store separately ?

Comment: Sorry, realised the wrong file name. Gave fixed the answer, the `org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.plugins.segment.SegmentNodeStoreService.config` file is needed for customBlobStore flag otherwise the FileDataStore config will be ignored. The S3 config file needs to be deleted (if present) otherwise the FileDataStore may also be ignored.